# "Error 'Self' is not defined" in member.edit

Tags: discord.py

I'm having issues with my code saying

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: edit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`

when I run the command. Self shouldn't need to be defined, right?
Also, when I do add self I get an issue with ctx.

The code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/")


@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx, member=discord.Member):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
    await member.edit(mute=True)


@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def leave(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()


client.run("Token")
```

Comment: You defined the variable "member" as the class discord.Member and not as the tpy eof the parameter. You should change ``member=discord.Member`` to ``member: discord.Member``

Answer (score 0):

I Managed to find the problem and fixed it.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/")


@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
    await ctx.author.edit(mute=True)

@client.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()


client.run("Token")
```

the problem is, you included `member` on your funcion. If you want it to send, edit, or do something with the message author just do `ctx.author` and it will be set on the author of the message.